# Chrome remote desktop resolution issue Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: display, google-chrome, display-resolution, remote-desktop

On a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install, I installed Chrome Remote Desktop and followed the instructions for making it actually work found in the highly referenced [Medium article](https://medium.com/@vsimon/how-to-install-chrome-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-52d99980d83e) (more details found on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/778028/configuring-chrome-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04/850359#850359)). When I connect to the computer remotely, the size of the screen is very small (probably around 1000x600 of the full 1920x1080). No amount of check mark clicking/unclicking in the chrome remote desktop settings change this. What is going on and how do I fix it?

More details:

- If I connect already in full screen mode, everything works just fine. If I connect not in full screen mode, the screen size goes wild.
- In `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop` I have `DEFAULT_SIZES = "1920x1080"` which is both the resolution of my local and remote computer.
- When the resolution issue is present, I can check the computer resolution under Displays and it is set to the proper resolution (1920x1080). If I choose a different resolution, the resolution changes (all windows change size), but the size of the display does not.

I would think there is supposed to be some auto detect screen size feature that is broken. I have tried adding a huge list of possible screen resolutions to the `DEFAULT_SIZES` entry, but this didn't fix it.